# Crosstab query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, view, crosstab

I have a table with two columns (Date, Subject), I have created a query from it
with three columns (MName, Subject, Counting) and also I have created a Dynamic crosstab query.

All of these I have done in MS Access easily.

My question is how can I create this 'Dynamic crosstab query' in SQL server.

[My Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R98Qs.png)

[Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjBXg.png)

[Dynamic Crosstab Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpbJZ.png)

Comment: Check out the discussion on [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query). That should give you some ideas of what to try.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Comment: Yes, It is. Please take a look at images I attached, I will be grateful if u Convert this access crosstab to sql server pivot